# Magento2: Admin panel content not loading

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

Certain areas of admin panel such as `Products, CMS Pages and Blocks` are not loading (loading gif keeps going forever). I can see other parts though such as `categories or widgets` and able to make changes and save them without any problem and website frontend reflects the changes but above mentioned elements won't load even if you refresh or log out and log back in.